# Simulation terminated with exit code: 1 (Omnet++)

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm going to use Omnet++ v4.6 with Inet v2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 since I need simuLTE.

I installed successfully Omnet++ and I built successfully Inet, but as soon as I try to run Inet, I get this error:

**Starting...

```
$ cd /home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/samples/inet/tests/module/lib
$ opp_run -r 0 -n ../../../examples:../../../src -l ../../../src/inet omnetpp.ini

<!> Error during startup: Obsolete section name [Cmdenv] found, please convert the ini file to 4.x format.

OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1

Working directory: /home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/samples/inet/tests/module/lib

Command line: opp_run -r 0 -n ../../../examples:../../../src -l ../../../src/inet omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:

PATH=/home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/bin::/home/milena/bin:/home/milena/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/milena/omnetpp-4.6/bin:/home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/lib::/home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/samples/inet/src:
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=/home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/images**
```

Thanks ad lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `inet/tests` contains unit tests (for developers of `INET` code). I suggest you to look at `examples` directory. For example:

```
cd /home/milena/Desktop/D2DTools/omnetpp-4.6/samples/inet/
cd examples/ethernet/arptest
opp_run -n ../..:../../../src/  -l ../../../src/inet
```

A clue: one can safely omit `omnetpp.ini` in the last command because by default `opp_run` uses the `omnetpp.ini` file.

Comment: Excuse me but I can't see how it could help me.. I tried to run

opp_run -n ../..:../../../src/  -l ../../../src/inet

but it says " command not found"

Comment: Check whether your `PATH` variable contains **proper** path to `bin` directory of your `OMNeT++`. Then type just `opp_run -h` - you should see a help for this command.